# Magento 2 Custom error Landing pages (500, 401 and etc)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3, custompage

I have a question on how to display those error pages except for 404 error page. because it can be created using cms page. I wonder why on how to create error pages like 500 and etc. I hope someone can help me. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, create a 500.html page in your document root (usually a public_html/ or www/ directory).This should probably be a static HTML page rather than anything dynamic (i.e. PHP). Then  Add the following rule to the start of your Magento .htaccess

```
## rewrite errors to 500 error document
RewriteRule ^report/.* 500.html [L,R=503]
```

This will then redirect any requests for an error report page using a 500 response code (Internal server error) and display the 500.html page in place of the standard Magento page.

Comment: Hi Kishan Thanks for your answer. I'll try this one. I'll feedback later thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Create new custom 500 page

[image]

**pub/errors/custom**

Create a new one or rename the local xml

**pub/errors/local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <skin>custom</skin>
</config>
```

Your custom 500 page

**pub/errors/custom/503.phtml**

```
<h1>Service Temporarily Unavailable Custom</h1>
<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.</p>
```

We can add more style:

**pub/errors/custom/css/styles.css**

Comment: Thanks Khoa, Your method is interesting. I'll try this one also thanks